# escape string in json android

Tags: android, json

when I put one in a objectJson it is adding escape characters automatically.

put the original

```
j.put("paif_start", "01/05/2012");
```

as it saves the put

```
{"paif_start":"01\/05\/2012"}
```

how to remove these escape characters?

Comment: Well you can build a regular exception or simply a replace. When you find "\/" you replace it with "/"

Comment: When you read the string the escape characters will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On the receiving end, if you really want to, you could just do

```
 `myJsonString = myJsonString.replaceAll("\\","");`
```

But do note that those escape characters in no way make the JSON invalid or otherwise semantically different -- the '/' character can be optionally escaped with '\' in JSON.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `.replaceAll("\\\\","")` ?